# MongoError : unable to run a project locally

Tags: mongodb, reactjs, frontend

I am trying to run the frond end of the project locally but it is giving this error:

> Server listening on port 8080 connection error:  { MongoError: failed
>   to connect to server [aman:27017] on first connect [MongoError:
>   getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND aman aman:27017]

Below is how my `/_config.js` looks

```
const hostname = 'localhost';
const port = '8080';

const secret = 'amangrk';
const debug = true;
const clientPort = 3000;

const mailgun_apiKey = 'amangrk';
const mailgun_domain = 'amangrk';

module.exports = {
  debug: debug,
  port: port,
  urlAndPort: 'http://' + hostname + ':' + port,
  hostName: hostname,
  clientHostName: hostname,
  clientPort: clientPort,
  clientHostNameAndPort: hostname + clientPort,
  redirectURL: 'http://' + hostname + ':' + clientPort + "/temp",
  preRender: false,
  url: 'http://' + hostname,
  secret: secret,
  filesDirectory: '/files',
  rootDirectory: __dirname,
  mailgun: {
    apiKey: mailgun_apiKey,
    domain: mailgun_domain
  }
};
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try with this command
mongo --host server ip address

*Provide server ip as localhost

Comment: Error parsing command line: the required argument for option '--host' is missing try 'mongo --help' for more information